# How Can I remove some element in a ReplaySubject in Rxjs?

Tags: angular, rxjs6

**Background:**

I am trying to write a message service with Rxjs and angular 6. I use a ReplaySubject to keep the sent messages, then subscriber even after message emited can get them. So the message can be cross different angular components.

I successfully implemented these, however, I meet a problem that for every new subscriber will get the all of messages in the ReplaySubject, I want to delete some particular messages in ReplaySubject. or even clear all the ReplaySubject.

**Question:**

- How can I delete some item inside a ReplaySubject?
- If impossible, is there any work around?
- If impossible nether, is there any way to create a new ReplaySubject, then copy the subscriber to the new ReplaySubject? so all subscriber can still receive messages.

Many thanks.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/51147023/6680611

Answer (score 1):

There are bunch of Rxjs operators. You probably need some of the [transforming or filtering](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators.html) operators. Simple `map()` could help too.

For ex. you could return replay subject, and use `asObservable`:

`replaySubject.asObservable().filter(i => i > 5 ).subscribe();`

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I want to clear the buffer of the replaySubject. I can use filter to do this, but with the time going, the replayBuffer would be super large.

Answer (score 0):

```
private replaySubject$ = new ReplaySubject<any[]>(1);
private array = <any[]>[];
array$ = this.replaySubject$
    .asObservable()
    .pipe(tap((array) => (this.array = array)));

delete(id: number): Observable<void> {
    return this.http.delete(id).pipe(
      tap(() => {
        this.array = this.array.filter((item) => item.id !== id);
        this.replaySubject$.next(this.array);
      })
    );
  }
```