# RxjS shareReplay : how to reset its value?

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, caching, rxjs, reactive-programming

I use `shareReplay` to call **only once** (like a cache) a webservice to retrieve some informations :

In my service :

```
getProfile(): Observable<Customer> {
    return this.callWS().pipe(shareReplay(1));
}
```

In multiple components :

```
this.myService.getProfile().subscribe(customer => {
    console.log('customer informations has been retrieved from WS :', customer);
});
```

Now I want to add a method to force refresh the informations (bypass shareReplay only once). I tried with storing my observable in a variable, and set it to null before re-initialize it, but it seems to break components subscriptions..

Any help ?

Thanks

Comment: I would use a state store (ngrx, ngxs)

Comment: I am having the same problem.. any updates edit your question.. thanks

Comment: Have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51147023/6680611

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I know this thread is old, but I think I know what the other answer meant about prepend a "reset" subject to push new values. Check this example:

```
private _refreshProfile$ = new BehaviorSubject<void>(undefined);

public profile$: Observable<Customer> = _refreshProfile$
  .pipe(
    switchMapTo(this.callWS()),
    shareReplay(1),
   );

public refreshProfile() {
  this._refreshProfile$.next();
}
```

In the above snippet, all `profile$` new subscribers will receive the latest emitted value (upon calling `callWS()` once). If you wish to "refresh" the Customer being shared, you would call "refreshProfile()". This would emit a new value going through `switchMapTo`, reassigning the replay value and also notifying to any `profile$` open subscriber.

Have a nice one

Comment: very nice solution

Answer (score 5):

The other answers are all fine, but rather than having to reset the actual shareReplayed observable, a simpler approach might just be caching the result like so:

```
protected profile$: Observable<Customer>;

getProfile$(): Observable<Customer> {
  if (!this.profile$) {
    this.profile$ = this.callWS().pipe(shareReplay(1));
  }

  return this.profile$;
}

resetProfile() {
  this.profile$ = null;
}
```

ref: https://blog.angularindepth.com/fastest-way-to-cache-for-lazy-developers-angular-with-rxjs-444a198ed6a6

Comment: Won't setting `this.profile = null;` stop updates for pre-existing subscribers?

Comment: @xcvbn existing subscribers only get a single emission in this scenario, so that's not an issue-

Comment: The performance impact might be negligible, but do note that if `getProfile` is involved in a view, that it runs on every change detection cycle. You basically move the "complexity" from the reset to the retrieve, which is probably fine in most cases - but depending on the context, that might be relevant.

Comment: Usually I would think getProfile$ wouldn't be called directly from the view, you would have  profile$ = getProfile$() as a class property, and then update profile$ to a new getProfile$ if you need to refresh

Comment: The big drawback here is that each subscriber that receives the profile will only ever have that profile (until they re-subscribe). The refresher approach allows you to ensure all previous active subscribers receive the new value immediately.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you can prepend a Subject that will inject the new value with `merge`:

```
private refresh$ = new Subject();

refreshProfile(...): void {
  this.refresh$.next(/* whatever */);
}

getProfile(): Observable<Customer> {
  return this.callWS().pipe(
    merge(this.refresh$),
    shareReplay(1),
  );
}
```

Comment: Don't know how it works but it works. I was having the same problem.