# Angular Observables: in this solution, how to pass parameter to callWS() method?

Tags: angular, typescript

This solution to use and reset shareReplay is from: [RxjS shareReplay : how to reset its value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54348406/rxjs-sharereplay-how-to-reset-its-value/56031703#comment113162080_56031703)

```
private _refreshProfile$ = new BehaviorSubject<void>(undefined);

public profile$: Observable<Customer> = _refreshProfile$
  .pipe(
    switchMapTo(this.callWS()),
    shareReplay(1),
   );

public refreshProfile() {
  this._refreshProfile$.next();
}
```

Comment: `this.callWS(param1, param2, ...)`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use switchMap. Use it as follows :

```
private _refreshProfile$ = new BehaviorSubject<number>(0);

public profile$: Observable<Customer> = _refreshProfile$
  .pipe(
    switchMap(userId => this.callWS(userId)),
    shareReplay(1),
   );

public refreshProfile(userId: number) {
    this._refreshProfile$.next(userId);
}

this.profile$.subscribe(console.log);
this.refreshProfile(20); // 20 will be passed as userId to callWS
```

StackBlitz reference: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ezaxsk?file=src/app/hello.component.ts

Comment: Thanks, but no. Your solution not get external parameter...

Comment: Hi, please go through the StackBlitz reference that I have added, it definitely works.

Comment: Yes, work fine!
My fault, sorry and many thanks!!