# RxJS webSocket Dynamic URL

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs6

I would like to allow a client to dynamically change the url to a `webSocket` and maintain Observables on connection to the new `webSocket`. Looking over the RxJS Github and Stackoverflow, this is not something that is supported by RxJS (see https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/4355)

The referenced Github links to a Stackoverflow ([Resetting ReplaySubject in RxJS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51145664/resetting-replaysubject-in-rxjs-6/51147023#51147023)) where a `resettable` is used to "reset" a subject.

Could this be used to dynamically modify the url of a `webSocket`?

https://github.com/cartant/rxjs-etc/blob/master/source/observable/resettable.ts

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
function resettable<T, U extends any[]>(
  factory: (...args: U) => WebSocketSubject<T>,
  ...args: U
): {
  readonly closed: boolean;
  readonly observable: Observable<T>;
  readonly subject: Subject<T>;
  reset(...args: U): void;
  unsubscribe(): void;
} {
  const resetter = new Subject<any>();
  const source = new Subject<T>();
  let destination = factory(...args);
  let subscription = source.subscribe(destination);
  return {
    reset(...args: U): void {
      subscription.unsubscribe();
      destination = factory(...args);
      subscription = source.subscribe(destination);
      resetter.next();
    },
    unsubscribe(): void {
      subscription.unsubscribe();
      /*tslint:disable:rxjs-no-subject-unsubscribe*/
      source.unsubscribe();
      /*tslint:enable:rxjs-no-subject-unsubscribe*/
    },
    get closed(): boolean {
      return subscription.closed;
    },
    get observable(): Observable<T> {
      return resetter.asObservable().pipe(
        startWith(null),
        switchMap(() => destination)
      );
    },
    get subject(): Subject<T> {
      return source;
    }
  };
}
```

If there are any other ways to accomplish this, I'm all ears! Thanks!

Comment: If your websocket result is observable, and it should emit values based on the latest destination, can't you have a stream of destinatios (like with a behaviorsubject). eg: `destination$.pipe(switchMap(destination => WebSocketThingamajiggy$(destination))`