# Angular 8: ReplaySubject Clear Delete History and Cache

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

In Angular, ReplaySubject returns the last value received, if receiver is late to subscribing.

The ReplaySubject is comparable to the BehaviorSubject in the way that it can send “old” values to new subscribers.

Is there anyways, someone can clear out the cache, and reset, so ReplaySubject has no history at all?

Here is my ReplayService method

Would like to add to the following method, to have a clearhistory method, etc

```
export class BasicReplayService {

  private messageSource = new ReplaySubject();
  currentMessage = this.messageSource.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  changeMessage(currentMessage) {
    this.messageSource.next(currentMessage);
  }
}
```

Comment: If you don't need history of values, use a simple Subject. If you subscribe afterwards, it will still subscribe to next emitted values.

Comment: Why can't you just re-initialize it?

Comment: hi @cs95 how would I do that? thanks

Comment: `reset() {  this.messageSource = new ReplaySubject(); }` Now new subscribers will only see the new observable with no history.

Comment: hi @cs95 what will happen to existing subscribers? are they unsuscribed?  I was testing my code, seems like it, I want existing subscribers to stay, thanks

Comment: That's fair, it seems like you'd need to ship your own implementation, this might be what you're looking for: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51145664/resetting-replaysubject-in-rxjs-6