# Unexpected output with delayed Observable when subscribing right after `next`ing

Tags: rxjs, timing, switchmap

Let's look at [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-5fsgpk?file=index.ts) piece of code:

```js
let isNull = true;
const a$ = new Subject<void>();
const b$ = a$.pipe(
  switchMap(() => {
    if (!isNull)
      return of(true).pipe(
        tap(() => console.log('should be shared')),
        delay(100) // (3)
      );
    else return of(null);
  }),
  shareReplay(1)
);

b$.subscribe((b) => console.log('1', b));
a$.next(); // (1)
b$.subscribe((b) => console.log('2', b));
isNull = false;
a$.next(); // (2)
b$.subscribe((b) => console.log('3', b));
```

The output is the following:

```
1 null
2 null
should be shared
3 null // *
1 true
2 true
3 true
```

Expected output:

```
1 null
2 null
should be shared
1 true
2 true
3 true
```

The line marked with `*` is not desired and I am unsure where it comes from. I *assume* that the last Observable `switchMap` returns is not the one updated by (2) but the old one from (1). If I remove the `delay` at (3), the line marked with `*` does not appear as expected. This sounds like a timing/ scheduling issue but I do not know a way

- to explain this exactly and to
- fix this elegantly and without unnecessary `next`ing

EDIT: Made the example more concise.

EDIT 2:

The reason why I am getting `null` is that during the time of the third subscription, `shareReplay` does not have the fresh value (`true`) yet. Instead, it returns the stale value, which is `null`. A partially correct workaround is to do this:

```js
let isNull = true;
const a$ = new Subject<void>();
const b$ = a$.pipe(
  switchMap(() => {
    if (!isNull)
      return of(true).pipe(
        tap(() => console.log('should be shared')),
        delay(100),
        shareReplay(1)
      );
    else return of(null).pipe(shareReplay(1));
  }),
      share()
);

b$.subscribe((b) => console.log('1', b));
a$.next();
b$.subscribe((b) => console.log('2', b));
isNull = false;
a$.next();
b$.subscribe((b) => console.log('3', b));

// Output:
/*
1 null
should be shared
1 true
2 true
3 true
*/
```

But as you see, the output "2 null" is missing. So, I am still not sure how to solve this issue elegantly.

Comment: The reason the `null` user is logged is because your first subscription is still subscribed, so the `userSubscriber` logic is executed each time `user$` emits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why `null` is logged instead of `true` is that the emission of `true` reaches the `shareReplay(1)` operator *after* it has already returned the previously buffered value (`null`) to the second subscriber.

This happens because the `delay` operator schedules the emission of `true` within a macrotask, which occurs *after* the synchronous subscription process is completed (wherein `shareReplay(1)` returns its buffered value to the subscriber). Therefore, the update of `shareReplay(1)`'s buffer does not happen in time or, to put it another way, the subscriber does not wait for the update to complete.

This should solve the problem (adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74306240/14878700)):

```js
let isNull = true;
const a$ = new Subject<void>();
const b$ = a$.pipe(
  map(() => {
    if (!isNull)
      return of(true).pipe(
        tap(() => console.log('should be shared')),
        delay(100),
        shareReplay(1)
      );
    else return of(null);
  }),
  shareReplay(1),
  switchAll()
);

b$.subscribe((b) => console.log('1', b));
a$.next();
b$.subscribe((b) => console.log('2', b));
isNull = false;
a$.next();
b$.subscribe((b) => console.log('3', b));

// Output:
/*
1 null
2 null
should be shared
1 true
2 true
3 true
*/
```